# Spring Boot override appplication.properties values while executing jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with application.properties file as shown below:

application.properties

```
mode=aws
target=production
```

During the execution of application jar, I want to override properties based on the environment.

But space-separated key and values are not overriding the configuration but setting it as empty.

```
java -jar spring-boot.jar --mode compose --target production
```

However, equal sign separated key values are fine perfectly.

```
java -jar spring-boot.jar --mode=compose --target=production
```

Is there any way or workaround to make the space-separated key-value options working?

In the actual use case, we need to run it in docker in AWS ECS and we will be passing other params as well, and by default, the arguments are populated with space-separated in the ECS template.

Answer (score 1):

If just the whitespace is the problem... have you tried to put it in quotes?

```
java -jar app.jar --name="Spring and Summer"
```

Also very helpful regarding overriding of properties [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try environment variables and [spring boot's relaxed binding rules](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables)

```
> MODE='compose it' TARGET='production it' java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.1)

2021-06-11 14:30:27.082  INFO 26666 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.11 on Stephens-MacBook-Pro-Late-2013.local with PID 26666 (/Users/sdoxsee/Downloads/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by sdoxsee in /Users/sdoxsee/Downloads/demo)
2021-06-11 14:30:27.088  INFO 26666 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-11 14:30:27.916  INFO 26666 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 6.525 seconds (JVM running for 7.162)
compose it
production it
```

If you need a tool to convert between properties, yaml or environment variables, you can use a tool I built for that purpose: http://env.simplestep.ca/